# NHibernate Criteria Queries Documentation

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

Does anyone know of a resource for Criteria Queries in NHibernate that demonstrates complex criteria restrictions.

For example

- select rows in the parent table and
  only rows in a child table that match
  a criteria
- set eager fetching on parent and
  child in the criteria

i.e. not just simple criteria, but something a bit more meaty. I have searched for a decent resource, but just find really simplistic examples and I need more advanced examples and explanations.

Comment: Hibernate documentation and examples could be used too. Because both NHibernate and Hibernate have same API.

Comment: @afsharm - That's great news. Do you have any links you can share that deal with Criteria Queries? Thanks.

Comment: I'm used to searching. Just search for it in google, for example try http://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate+icriteria&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=KLV&pwst=1&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&&sa=X&ei=Znq9TPW6H4e8sQPm9b3IDA&ved=0CBUQvwUoAQ&q=hibernate+criteria&spell=1&fp=fad0bccbc44b8016

Comment: @afsharm - I get your point, but I was suggesting you could add your comment as the answer, then I can tick it and you'll get points as you've helped!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate documentation and examples could be used too. Because both NHibernate and Hibernate have same API. An easy way to get documentation and examples is to google it. For example try [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate+icriteria&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=KLV&pwst=1&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&&sa=X&ei=Znq9TPW6H4e8sQPm9b3IDA&ved=0CBUQvwUoAQ&q=hibernate+criteria&spell=1&fp=1&cad=b).

Comment: Thanks for this - that means there is a lot more documentation than I thought!